# Does peering between vnets create congestion?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, vnet

[image]

### Problem

As you can see in the image, I have 2 vnets and both have NAT Gateways. Vnet 2 has one VM which wants to connect internet but I can't allow it directly. So want to introduce one proxy server (squid proxy) in between VM and NAT Gateway.

But I have a question, **where should I add that proxy? & Why? In vnet 1 or vnet 2?**

It will work in both cases but I think adding proxy in vnet 1 will create congestion in peering.

Answer (score 0):

Put the proxy in vnet1 and remove the NATGW from vnet2.

Easiest solution.